# Restore database from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, sql-server-2008-r2

I am new to Oracle 11g Express. I have a database on my SQL Server 2008 R2 and I want to restore it in Oracle. How to do it? Thanks

Comment: see http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/mssqlserver/migrate_microsoft_sqlserver_otn.htm

Comment: You **cannot** restore a SQL Server backup to Oracle - no way. What you'll need to do is script out the database structure (and possibly the data as well) into SQL script on your SQL Server machine, adapt those T-SQL script from SQL Server to be compatible with Oracle's PL/SQL, and then run those on Oracle.

Comment: @marc_s sorry for being beginner. Can you provide me some links or video on how to do it?.

Comment: Are you trying to migrate or restore SQL server backup on to Oracle ?

Comment: My database from SQL Server to Oracle. Migrate? sorry don't know the term.

Answer (score 0):

For migrating Oracle databases to SQL Server databases, you can use SSMA aka SQL Server Migration Assistant

Please read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313159(v=sql.110).aspx
for step by step migration process

Comment: From SQL Server databases to Oracle Database